Button color flickering when validating error using useEffect
In my React Native component, I use the useEffect hook to validate the value on each input press. According to the result of the validation function, I make a button color grey (non validated) or actionColor (input correctly validated).
Issue is each time validation is triggered on input press, button color appears validated (actionColor) for a few milliseconds. How can I fix this? I tried debouncing but it just made the button look validated and then back to not validated for 500ms.
My code:
export default FilterCard1 = observer((props) => {

    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const root = useStore();
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState({});
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [remaining, setRemaining] = useState(0);
    const [required, setRequired] = useState(0);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);


    // Description validation using useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        validateDescription(false);
    }, [root.userStore.description]);

    const validateDescription = (showErrorBanner = true) => 
    {
        let stringError = '';
    
        // Validation logic using if/else
        if (root.userStore.description === '') {
            stringError = t('descriptionFieldIsRequired');
        } else if (root.userStore.description.length <= 25) {
            stringError = t('descriptionFieldIsTooShort');
        } else if (root.userStore.description.length > root.userStore.descriptionMaxChars) {
            stringError = t('descriptionFieldIsTooLong', { maxDescriptionChars: root.userStore.descriptionMaxChars });
        }
    
        // Show error banner if needed
        if (showErrorBanner) {
            root.mapStore.showError(stringError);
        }
    
        // Set the error state
        setError(stringError);
    
        // Return whether the validation passed (no error)
        return stringError === '';
    };
    


    const onNewDescription = (newValue) => {
        //setBody(newValue);
        setError('');
        root.mapStore.showError('');
        root.userStore.setDescription(newValue);
        setRemaining(Number(root.userStore.descriptionMaxChars) - Number(newValue.length));
        setRequired(Math.abs(Number(newValue.length) - 30));
    };


    const clickedNext = () => 
        {
            if(validateDescription(true))
            {
                props.onNext();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        };


    const calculateDescriptionRemainingCharacters = (currentLength) => {
        let maxLength = root.userStore.descriptionMaxChars;
        return maxLength - currentLength;
    }





    return (

        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                <TextInput 
                    spellcheck={false} blurOnSubmit={true} returnKeyType="done"
                    value={root.userStore.description}
                    onChangeText={newValue => onNewDescription(newValue)}
                    style={[styles.textInputContainer, isFocused ? styles.focusedInput : styles.unfocusedInput, { minHeight: 275, textAlignVertical: 'top' }]}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent" placeholder={t('writeYourPlansHere')}
                    placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
                    numberOfLines={10} multiline={true} 
                    onSubmitEditing= {(event) => ( clickedNext() ) }
                    onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
                    onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
                    />
                
            </View>
            <CircleButton onPress={() => { clickedNext() }} disabled={error != ''}></CircleButton>
                {/*
               <ButtonCard2 onPress={() => { clickedNext() }} loader={loader} title={t('next')} expand={true} disabled={!!error}></ButtonCard2>
               */}
               {!!root.userStore.description && root.userStore.description != '' && (

<Text allowFontScaling={false} style={{ padding:10, color: 'rgb(125,125,125)', position: 'absolute',bottom:0,left:0, fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'IBMPlexSans-Regular', marginBottom: 0, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}>{t('currentCharacters', { characters: calculateDescriptionRemainingCharacters(root.userStore.description.length) })}</Text>
)}
        </View>

    );

});

My CircleButton:
export default CircleButton = observer((props) => {
    const {  textColor = 'white' , bgColor = 'rgb(188, 19, 108)', disabled = false, iconName = 'chevron-right' } = props;
    //const navigation = useNavigation();
    const root = useStore();
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {


    }, []);

    const onClicked = () => {
        props.onPress()
    };



    return (

        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => { onClicked() }} style={{ width: 75, height: 75, borderRadius: 75/2, elevation:3, alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',position: 'absolute', bottom:0,right:0, ...disabled ? {backgroundColor:'rgb(235,235,235)'} : { backgroundColor:bgColor } }} >
            {root.userStore.initialLoader == 1 ?
                <ActivityIndicator animating={true} size={30} color={textColor} />
                :
                <MaterialCommunityIcon name={iconName} style={{ fontSize: 47, color: textColor, marginLeft:3 }} />
            }
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );


});


Consider using EsLint with React plugins. Your problem is most likely that you don't pass validateDescription as a hook dependency. You need to wrap it (and all dependent functions) in useCallback
